# how to fix button position when resolution is changed in unity after built

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

When I add a button and play the game in Unity editor, it remains in its required position. But when I build and run it, the button's position gets misplaced. I want 1366 x 768 screen resolution with all buttons well positioned.

Comment: How exactly are you adding said button? Do you use the new UI system? Can you post screenshot of inspector window with the button's game object selected?

Comment: Also, please define "well positioned". Do you want your button position relative to the center of the screen to be the same? Or relative to the left-up corner? Measured in pixels or % of the screen?

Comment: @MaxYankov yes, I am using UI system unity 5.0.0. My game has a strip at the bottom and on this there is a menu button. By <i> well positioned </i> I mean that I want this button at left on the strip. I can't provide screen shot, excuse.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Canvas Scaler (to control the scale of your game on several devices) and Anchors (to keep the elements in the position where you want to) on your buttons.

http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario where your buttons are normal size in the editor and exporting to your phone makes them smaller, make sure your Canvas has the Canvas Scaler component, and set the UI Scale Mode to "Scale With Screen Size".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).